# Activity and thread handling

Tags: android, progressdialog, ksoap2

I want to make an http request (I use ksoap2) in the `onCreate()` during this time I want to have a `ProgressDialog` on screen to block the user. Once the request is done, I want to finish my onCreate using the elements that I retrieve from my http request.

For now:

I have a class which implements Runnable. I instantiate it in my onCreate. This class make the http request, during this time a ProgressDialog is on the screen. Once it's done the ProgressDialog is dismissed. But since it's not in the UI thread the following of the onCreate is executed before getting the result of the http request.

I also tried, at first: in the onCreate I do a `show()` of my ProgressDialog then the http request then a `dismiss()` ProgressDialog and finally finish my onCreate with the result of my http request... it's ok except that the ProgressDialog is not showing this time.

Sorry for the messy explanations, my english is really not helping either.

Anyway, ideas ?

Thanks.

PS : BTW I know AsyncTask is better, it is what I usually use but having it with a ProgressDialog is not at all easy.

**My question is more : is there a way in an `onCreate()` to make an http request to get the value of an `int`. While this request is made: showing a `ProgressDialog` to block the user but also block the UI thread so that the end of the onCreate can use the value retrieved by the http request once it is complete.**

An ugly way would be a loop in the onCreate with a sleep waiting for the value to be retrieved... that's really ugly.

Comment: You should go for the AsyncTask even though it's not as easy. It's the right solution for your problem.

Comment: If I solve my problem I certainly will go back to this. I edit my question to be clearer... I hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I know you mentioned you didn't want to use `AsyncTask` due to the complexities of showing the `ProgressDialog`, but unless I'm missing something it should be as simple as the below. Alternatively, you could use a handler to fire the call back?

I think you need some kind of handler to callback once the `HTTP` request is done, and then in the callback finish off your code.

I also use `ksoap2` for a web service call and show a `ProgressDialog` whilst it's called. Once the web server call is finished, it raises an event and I close the `ProgressDialog`. I'm not sure if this will help you, but I have the following (of course, there may be better ways, but this works for me), this way the `ProgressDialog` is called on the UI thread, an `AsyncTask` completes and calls the complete method (which returns the thread back to the UI) and I dismiss the dialog:

```
    // Notify user the web service is connecting
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            Screen_GlobalLeaderboard.this, "Getting scores",
            "Please wait...", true);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    WebService ws = new WebService(this) {

        @Override
        public void webServiceCallComplete(boolean success, Object data,
                String errorMessage, WebMethods callingWebMethod) {


            dialog.dismiss();

            // Your complete code here
        }
    };

    ws.getTopLeaderboardResults(top, gameMode);
```

Edit: I think what you're asking is `onCreate` (ran from the UI thread), you want to show a `ProgressDialog` and in the same method return a value from an HTTP request and once it completes, hide the dialog.

You then say you've tried that and the `ProgressDialog` does not show. This is because you block the UI thread with the HTTP request.

Providing you call the HTTP request from the `onCreate` method, you must run it in a separate thread (or as you done, implement `Runnable`) and a handler which will call the runnable with which you can then handle the return value.

Put simply, you can't:

Show `ProgressDialog` > Call HTTP request > Get value > Hide `ProgressDialog` without adding another thread for the HTTP request (or the `ProgressDialog` will not show) which in turn means your return HTTP request code must be outside of the calling `onCreate` method.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know what is WebService nor the override method. Thanks.

Comment: WebService is an abstract class which calls an AsyncTask, once it completes, it calls `webServiceCallComplete` and you can dismiss the dialog. Alternatively, use load the `ProgressDialog`, run a thread to do the work and use a handler to call a `runnable` to dismiss the dialog and do what you want with the return value.

Comment: Ok I get it. I edit my question, because it is much more about blocking the UI thread waiting for result while displaying a ProgressDialog. Once it is done dismiss the dialog and 'resume' the on create using the result obtain.

Comment: I understand your problem. The ProgressDialog does not appear when you do not implement `Runnable` as (and I think you know) the HTTP request is called on the same thread, so it processes this without showing the ProgressDialog. I don't think you _really_ want to continue your code on the actual `onCreate` method itself. You'll call it from there, and your Handler will call the runnable outside of the `onCreate` method, but it doesn't matter. You can't wait for a reply and show the dialog at the same time in the onCreate method as you're blocking the thread. You must call a handler.

Comment: Updated my answer to hopefully help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your `oncreate` show `dialog first`, then create a `thread` and do your `http task` there and once you are done with that call the `handler` from the thread and `dismiss` your dialog.

Comment: It works as fine as with my solution by putting the Dialog in the Runnable Class. Thanks.